# necesito ingresar una nueva columna en mysql pero no me deja

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, date

estuve ingresando columnas normail mente pero al crear una tipo date me aparece el siguiente error

```
      SQL query:


          ALTER TABLE `asignacion_tablet`  ADD `inicio` DATE NOT NULL  
          AFTER `Celular`;MySQL said: Documentation

           #1292 - Incorrect date value: '0000-00-00' for column 'inicio' at row 1
```

agradezco su ayuda

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque solo pusiste una imagen de tu excepción](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2873/)

Comment: entonces que pongo mas? si ese es el error

Comment: Sigue el enlace que te dejé. No creo que lo hayas leído tan rápido. Pero considera que tu imágen no muestra todos los detalles. Hay partes importantes que quedaron cortadas. Esa es una de la razones por la que se debe evitar limitarse a poner imagenes.

Comment: En lugar de colocar la imagen, pudiste haber copiado el texto completo del error. Es mejor el texto que la imagen @KevinSalazar

Comment: pero haber 1. ya lo lei por encima y dice que intente poner en pocas palabras mas contenido pero en este caso que puedo meter mas si no y hay mas solo intento crear una columna tipo date y no me deja ya esta ese es el error y adjunto la imagen del error

Comment: @Kevin: Me repito. La imagen solo muestra ***parcialmente*** el mensaje de error. Por eso es mejor copiar el texto. Nota que falta el final de la sentencia `ALTER TABLE ...`

Comment: ah bn si tu lo dices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya lo soluciones graciasLa solución es porque en Mysql a partir de la versión 5.7 está activado por defecto el modo estricto que no permite añadir en campos de fecha 0000-00-00 solo hay que poner la columna null y ya esta

Comment: Te recomiendo eliminar esta respuesta y la pregunta, ya que te estas llenando de votos negativos sin sentido, y realmente no estas explicando cual era el problema y porque esta es la solucion (mas alla que lo solucione)

Comment: La solución es porque en Mysql a partir de la versión 5.7 está activado por defecto el modo estricto que no permite añadir en campos de fecha `0000-00-00`. Efectivamente, hay que poner la columna a null. Si editas tu respuesta añadiendo esta información es posible que no recibas tantos votos negativos...

Comment: ok gracias por tu consejo